# Avoid cursor's default position on webpage being (0,0)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

in the jsfiddle below im trying to get the yellow and red circles to **initially appear in the center**, as opposed to *moving to the cursor's initial assumed position* - which is (0,0) as the cursor is not yet in the actual screen of the page (if I'm guessing correctly).

http://jsfiddle.net/fhmkf/220/

Is there a way I can define the initial placement of the cursor - that is when calculating `(window).mousemove(function(e){...` - particularly the `e.pageX` and `e.pageY`?

The js looks like so:

```
var Circle = function(container, follower, r){
    var center = {
        x: $(container).width()/2 - r, 
        y: $(container).height()/2 - r
    };
    var distanceThreshold = $(container).width()/2 - r;
    var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;

    $(window).mousemove(function(e){ 
        var d = {
            x: e.pageX - center.x,
            y: e.pageY - center.y
        };
        var distance = Math.sqrt(d.x*d.x + d.y*d.y);
        if (distance < distanceThreshold) {
            mouseX = e.pageX;
            mouseY = e.pageY;
        } else {
            mouseX = d.x / distance * distanceThreshold + center.x;
            mouseY = d.y / distance * distanceThreshold + center.y;
        }
    });

    // cache the selector
    var follower = $(follower);
    var xp = 0, yp = 0;
    var loop = setInterval(function(){
        // change 12 to alter damping higher is slower
        xp += (mouseX - xp) / 2;
        yp += (mouseY - yp) / 2;
        follower.css({left:xp, top:yp});

    }, 30);
};

var c1 = new Circle(".container", "#follower", 15);
var c2 = new Circle(".container2", "#follower2", 25);
```

Comment: The cursor is definitely *not* at (0,0) by default. The cursor's first position is where ever it first moves. If it appears to be initialized to 0,0, it's because you're initializing *your* variables to 0,0.

Comment: Ah yes! You're right! Found the problem, initializing the wrong vars - supposed to initial `var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;`. Thanks!